# how to get parameter value from database using laravel

Tags: laravel-4

Im tring to get parameter value from database using laravel,for update a value .

```
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
```

`Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder::open()` must be of the type array, string given, called in

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\lara1\lara\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 211 and defined (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lara1\lara\app\views\newsandevents\edit.blade.php)

http://ErrorException
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder.php95
```

**this is my route code**

```
Route::get('/edit/{id}',array('uses'=>'NewsandeventsController@edit','as' => 'edit'));

 Controller.php
public function edit($id) 
      {     
      $newsevents=ForumNewsevent::find($id);
        return View::make('newsandevents.edit')
      ->with('newsevents',$newsevents);
}
```

Comment: And your view? Are you perhaps passing a string instead of an array in your form open?

Comment: I thing you are not give any parameter in `Form::open()` method. The parameter type must be in array.